# Modify a file to remove repeated occurances using scripts

Tags: shell, file, repeat

input

```
# FILE:app/src/file1.c, something_over_here
something_over_here
# FILE:app/src/file1.c, something_over_here
something_over_here
# FILE:app/src/file2.c, something_over_here
something_over_here
# FILE:app/src/file2.c, something_over_here
something_over_here
...........
```

output

```
# FILE:app/src/file1.c, something_over_here
something_over_here
# FILE:app/src/file2.c, something_over_here
something_over_here
..........
```

I have an input file which consists of repeated occurrences of lines having same filename. I need to delete all except the first occurrence of each filename. How do I proceed? I am not very familiar with scripts(python/shell). I need to know which direction to proceed in.

Comment: What do those `something_over_here` lines contain? Your output has some of them removed too, but which ones should be removed?

Comment: The question is unclear.  Is "something_over_here" an arbitrary string.  Does `# FILE:app/src/file1.c, foo` count as the same line as `# FILE:app/src/file1.c, bar`?  Is the text after a duplicate header line being deleted along with the header line?

Comment: @ilkkachu something_over_here is related to the line which is present above it and it should also be removed i.e., the text after the duplicate header should also be removed along with the duplicate header.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Making many assumptions about what you actually want, try:

```
awk '/^#/ {p=H[$2]++} !p ' input > output
```

This simply scans the file and increments a counter when it sees a line beginning with a '#'.  The counter is kept for each filename (column 2 in the line beginning with a comment), and a line does not print if the counter for the most recently seen file has been seen before.

Comment: can I just print the the required columns and ignore other columns of the header in the output file ? @William Pursell

Comment: Not sure exactly what you mean.  But perhaps you are looking for `awk '/^#/{ NF=2; p=H[$2]++} !p'`